# AEM forms: capturing the completed form and storing it in a database for later viewing

Tags: aem

I am not using AEM yet, in fact I just [stumbled onto it this morning,](https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6-1/html5-forms/feature-differentiation-html5-forms-pdf-forms.html) and it may have turned my plans upside down and inside out.

I have been sketching out the design for a secure web portal that would use interactive PDFs with form fields and an electronic signature as a way for our provider network to transmit signed documents back to headquarters. These documents contain large amounts of free-form text (case notes) as well as specific structured information, like dates of service.

If we were to use AEM forms instead of interactive PDFs, is it possible for a web app to obtain the completed and signed (scribbled on) form, such that the bytes of it could be downloaded and stored in a SQL database for later rendering later in a viewer in a .NET desktop app? Is there a .NET Viewer for AEM forms? Or would we simply use an embedded browser?

Can the filled-in AEM form be converted into a PDF? We might need to fax it.